# tcp reset from server

Tags: .net, tcp, iis-10

We operate a Windows Server 2019 environment where our applications are hosted within IIS 10.0. To facilitate seamless integration, we rely on a REST API over HTTPS (port 443). However, we've encountered an intermittent issue that some of our clients have reported. Occasionally, when attempting to connect to our API, the TCP handshake process is successful, but at times, they encounter 'TCP-RST-From-Server' errors.

It's important to note that our infrastructure doesn't involve load balancers or firewalls. Instead, we've configured network security group (NSG) rules within Microsoft Azure, specifically allowing traffic on port 443 with a broad 'any-to-any' permission.

If you have any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue, we would greatly appreciate your input and guidance.

We have diligently examined all available logs and conducted thorough testing, including traceroutes, and utilizing Wireshark. Our analysis reveals that TCP resets are indeed occurring. To resolve this issue, we are actively seeking a solution.

Furthermore, we have conducted tests from our server's end using the Wireshark tool, and our findings confirm the same 'TCP-RST' response.

[image]

Comment: If indeed the testing is done, can you tell if the TCP RST is directly from this Windows Server 2019 machine, but not from anything in between? The culprit can be any network device on the wire, so you need to be very careful. You also need to monitor the work load proactively, and see if RST occurs under high loads. It is usually a red flag to see a web app without any load balancing mechanism.

Comment: Tcp rst is the response from the client

Comment: Please try not to say just a few words, as that came without context and can be rather ambiguous. If you meant that from network packet analysis that TCP connections were broken because the client machine (not this Windows Server machine) sent out TCP RST to disconnect, then I don't think anything you did on the server side matters right now. You will have to gain access to that client machine and learn more from there. Hire an experienced consultant, as an internet forum can only help this far.

Comment: The Wireshark screen shot below does reveal the error pattern (TCP RST from the server machine, right after the client side sent Client Hello for TLS handshakes. You will have to dig further into HTTPERR logs and Schannel logs, and they might explain the cause.

Comment: While investigating the HTTPERR log, we encountered the following error: 'Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue.' Additionally, in the SCHANNEL log, we noticed the error message: 'A worker process with a process ID of '11712,' serving application pool 'xxxx,' was shut down due to inactivity. The Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes, and a new worker process will be initiated as required.

Comment: If you use search engines or modern AI to study further on `Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue` you will see what are the common causes and how to diagnose further. In short, likely you hit a performance issue and a lot of experience is required to move forward. So, if you can afford, hire a consultant or open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com for guidance.